# Where can I find "Ginga Sengoku Gunyuuden Rai" manga?

Tags: resources

I just wanna read *Ginga Sengoku Gunyuuden Rai* even though it is written in Japanese, Chinese, or any language at all, no need to be translated.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Please note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so only legal/official sites are allowed if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of its Japanese title 「銀河戦国群雄伝ライ」returned [Sukima (Japanese)](https://www.sukima.me/book/title/gomabooks0000652/) that allows the visitors to read all chapters for free and without registration (it's a legal site based on its [ABJ mark](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/56615/2516) on the footer).

Other than that, various Japanese bookstores like [Amazon Kindle](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B07DP8Q78P) and [Bookwalker](https://bookwalker.jp/series/164105/) also sell them in digital.